# Generate a dynamic query accepting any Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to create a query with LINQ, and then I want to assign the query generated to an entity class.
For example I have three entities with the same columns.

- A | Name, Lastname
- B | Name, Lastname
- C | Name, Lastname

For example I can generate a Linq Where Closures doing first a var who contains the select of the entity.

```
var lQuery = A.Select(t => t);
```

Then I add the closures if the Name or the LastName is not null

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pName))
{
    lQuery = lQuery.Where(x => x.Name == pName);                    
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pLastName))
{
    lQuery = lQuery.Where(x => x.LastName == pLastName);
}
```

And finally I return a list of A from the generated lQuery.

Is there a way to generate a query and then assign it at the end to one of my entities?

Comment: post some code snippets please so we can see what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you are looking for IQueryable<TEntity>, check this out: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1240553/LINQ-Part-An-Introduction-to-IQueryable

Comment: `Is there a way to generate a query and then assign it at the end to one of my entities?`-This is not clear to me. Are you expecting a generalized query and filtering for all three entities?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I don't know if using **IQueryable<T>** works, I'm trying with **IQueryable** with another class who contains the same columns from the entities tables.

Comment: @JohanSánchez Please check my updated answer. I have check it in my side and it works.

Comment: @JohanSánchez Has my answer worked for you? Please check my answer. I have given double solution.

Comment: Let me check, @TanvirArjel I think it should work. ;)

Comment: As I said, your code works very well! @TanvirArjel

Comment: @Great! to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
public async Task<List<object>> GetFilteredEntityList(string entityClassName, string name, string lastName)
{
      var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == entityClassName);

      if (type != null)
      {
         DbSet dbSet = _dbContext.Set(type);

         IQueryable entityListQueryable = dbSet;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
         {
              entityListQueryable = entityListQueryable.Where("Name == @0", name);
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
         {
              entityListQueryable = entityListQueryable.Where("LastName == @0", lastName);
         }

         return await entityListQueryable.ToListAsync();
     }
     else
     {
        throw new Exception("Table name does not exist with the provided entity class name");
     }
}
```

And the **Generic** version of the above method is:

```
public class FilterEntity<TEntity> where TEntity: class
{
    YourDbContext _dbContext = new YourDbContext();
    public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetFilteredEntityList(string name, string lastName)
    {
        DbSet<TEntity> dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

        IQueryable<TEntity> entityListQueryable = dbSet;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            entityListQueryable = entityListQueryable.Where("Name == @0", name);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
        {
            entityListQueryable = entityListQueryable.Where("LastName == @0", lastName);
        }

        return await entityListQueryable.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
List<Teacher> teachreList = await new FilterEntity<Teacher>().GetFilteredEntityList("Tanvir", null);
```

**Note: Don't forget to install `System.Linq.Dynamic` from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)**

Comment: In this code, are you using **System.Linq;**??, I can't use the **Where** closure from **entityListQueryable**

Comment: Please check my updated answer . I missed to tell you to install `System.Linq.Dynamic`